# Does Dubai enforce professionally-sampled Covid tests?

Tags: covid-19, dubai

For flyers to Dubai (via Emirates Airlines, from the UK, if that matters), the [Emirates website says the covid test must be professionally sampled](https://www.emirates.com/uk/english/help/covid-19/dubai-travel-requirements/tourists/#:%7E:text=The%20test%20sample%20must%20be%20collected%20by%20a%20certified%20healthcare%20professional%20and%20processed%20at%20a%20laboratory.%20All%20self%E2%80%91administered%20tests%2C%20even%20those%20in%20person%20witnessed%20or%20supervised%20by%20a%20registered%20healthcare%20professional%2C%20will%20not%20be%20accepted.):

> The test sample must be collected by a certified healthcare professional and processed at a laboratory. All self‑administered tests, even those in person witnessed or supervised by a registered healthcare professional, will not be accepted.

Does anyone have any experience with this specific condition being enforced?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.